# Button.setOnClickListener() is not working in my code

Tags: android

I have created a button and used the setOnClickListner() method on the button. But when I am trying to run and clicking the button its not working.

```
package com.example.administrator.sportsspeaker;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private TextView textViewKickSpeed,textViewKickPower;
    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewKickSpeed = findViewById(R.id.textKickSpeed);
        textViewKickPower = findViewById(R.id.textKickPower);
        button = findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("working","");
//                ParseObject kickBoxing = new ParseObject("KickBoxing");
//                kickBoxing.put("KickSpeed",""+textViewKickSpeed.getText());
//                kickBoxing.put("KickPower",""+textViewKickPower.getText());
//                kickBoxing.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void done(ParseException e) {
//                        if(e == null){
//
//                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully uploaded ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
//                                    .show();
  //                      }
 //                   }
 //              });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textKickSpeed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="kickSpeed"
        android:inputType="text|number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textKickPower"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="kickpower"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textKickSpeed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="submit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textKickPower" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Error Code:**

```
2018-12-31 19:52:20.065 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:52:20.404 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:52:20.742 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:52:21.024 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:52:21.437 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:52:21.773 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:52:22.161 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:53:43.315 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:53:43.544 4605-4630/com.example.administrator.sportsspeaker E/EGL_emulation: tid 4630: eglSurfaceAttrib(1354): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
2018-12-31 19:53:43.604 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:53:43.887 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:53:44.180 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:53:44.525 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:53:44.906 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:53:45.254 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:53:45.633 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 19:53:45.960 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:11:11.549 521-551/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2018-12-31 20:14:31.072 521-551/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2018-12-31 20:15:10.026 320-342/? E/BandwidthController: Updating quota globalAlert failed (Status[code: 2, msg: "[No such file or directory] : fopen("/proc/net/xt_quota/globalAlert", "we") failed"])
2018-12-31 20:18:37.550 521-551/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2018-12-31 20:18:37.578 424-441/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(0xf192c960:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2018-12-31 20:18:37.579 424-441/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf192c960:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2018-12-31 20:18:37.905 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:38.223 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:38.495 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:38.822 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:39.165 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:39.487 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:39.784 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:40.052 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:40.389 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:40.723 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:41.048 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:18:41.315 379-405/? E/AudioStreamOutSink: Error while writing data to HAL: -61
2018-12-31 20:32:59.553 521-551/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Just to understand your question better - if you move your "setOnClickListener" to "on create life cycle "  will  the error occur ?

Comment: Its already inside onCreate() @TamirAbutbul

Comment: I ment on start ,my mistake

Comment: Same error bro even after moving setOnClick() to onStart()@TamirAbutbul

Comment: on clicking button the setOnClickListner() not executing .Take a look at error@TheWanderer

Comment: How do you look at your logcat - are you only showing errors ? or you also show the printings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I can see you have printed info log with `Log.i()`, but from your log it's clear that you are looking only the **Error** logs in *logcat*.

You can just change the logs view type to **Info** in *logcat* or change your log printing to `Log.e()`.

Also you did not put any log message into your log print, it's not mandatory but helpful. The first part you write in the method **"working"** is not message, just a tag. Message can be written like following:

`Log.i("working", "your log message here");`

Comment: Happy to help you @AashishSharma, if your problem solved please mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Log.i("working","");
```

Try

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button Pressed ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This way you don't have to rely on logs.

I know this doesn't answer your question, but could help your debugging in the future

As for answering your question, try setting the click listener later in the lifecycle, like in onStart()